# Attach multiple libraries to a cluster terraforming Databricks

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I'm currently trying to attach more than one maven artifact to my terraform configuration of a cluster. 
In the documentation, nothing says it can't work. It is only specified that one type of library must correspond to one configuration block. 

How can we add more than one artifact in my terraform configuration ?

Comment: I missread the documentation: 'one must specify each library in its configuration block' so it was kinda clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If finally did it by duplicating my configuration blocks.

```
library {
  maven {
    coordinates = "..."
  }
}
library {
  maven {
    coordinates = "..."
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, it's a correct solution... I'll change the wording slightly to make it more clear

Comment: I hesitated writing an enhancement on your github :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic library block which will repeat it for you. An example for Python packages where listOfPythonPackages is a variable list.

```
  dynamic "library" {
    for_each = toset(var.listOfPythonPackages)
    content {
      pypi {
        package = library.value
      }
    }
  }
```